# Импорт сторонних библиотек с помощью мобильного IDE

Tags: java, mobile

Пишу код с телефона(Пользуюсь IDE Dcoder),и возникла необходимость импортировать стороннюю библиотеку. Я её скачиваю,прописываю путь в .dcoder_run . В итоге программа выдает ошибку о том,что данной библиотеки не существует(does not exist).
Вопрос: как грамотно прописать путь к библиотеке? Ну или подскажите IDE,в которой импорт не столь проблематичен

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Я конечно понимаю, что возможно нет возможности иметь компьютер, но Вам не кажется, что телефон не предназначен для кодинга?